# how to get multiple kendo ui templates from external file using jquery in a single call

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, kendo-ui

Hi i have on issue regarding externalizing kendo templates.I have multiple templates (4 to 5 templates) in single html page.I want to load those templates in a single call instead of calling for each template.I want to implement it on jquery code.can any one please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the [official Kendo way](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/load-remote) works:

I implemented the [templateLoader.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3087987).

And in the HTML template file, you can do:

```
<!-- template 1 -->
<script type="text/html" id="editProductPopupTpl">
    <!-- template content -->
</script>

<!-- template 2 -->
<script type="text/html" id="editProductPopupTpl">
    <!-- template content -->
</script>
```